# Adding Country column from city column in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I am new to python and can't find a blog post or anything answering my question online.

I have datasheets with these columns: 'City', 'Distribution', 'Reference'

The problem I am running into is that the 'City' column also has countries in it. Example photo attached. Each list of cities is attached to a country.. (Africa, Asia, Europe, North America, Oceania, and South America are the countries in all the datasheets)

I need to add a column named 'Country' and I am hoping to find a systematic way in python to have it read the country from the city column and manually put the right country in for me next to the appropriate cities. Any ideas?

I have been trying to find somewhere with the answer to my question, but the tutorials I find use str.split(',') or some command like that, which does not help in my case.

[image]

Comment: It's worse. You have continents, countries and areas/cities in the City column. To sort that out, you will need a list of continents and countries, so the program has a chance to know what it deals with.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
with open('sample.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    city_split = row["City"].split(",")
    if len(city_split) > 1:
        row["Country"] = city_split[0]
```

Comment: Great answer! but you can make it better by adding some explanation.